# Animation is not working

Tags: android

Can any one tell me why animation is not working with below code. And and also tell me how to make slide out up. I am trying my level so as may possible let me how to do this. One more thing I am using mapping concept in below code. If any clarification required let me know

```
public class Erispage2Activity extends Activity 
{
    ErisImageMap ErisImageMap;
    MediaPlayer audioStory;
    Button play;
    Button stop;
    TextView txtPage1;
    private SeekBar volumeSeekbar = null;
    private AudioManager audioManager = null; 
    Animation animation;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
         setContentView(R.layout.page1);

         audioStory = new MediaPlayer();
         audioStory = MediaPlayer.create(Erispage2Activity.this, R.raw.november_titanic);

         play=(Button) findViewById(R.id.erispage2play);
         stop=(Button)  findViewById(R.id.erispage2stop);

         txtPage1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPage);

         ErisImageMap = (ErisImageMap)findViewById(R.id.map);
         ErisImageMap.setImageResource(R.drawable.learningui);

         volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);

//         volumeSeekbar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.seekbg);

         setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
         initControls();

         txtPage1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                audioStory.start();
            }
        });

        ErisImageMap.addOnImageMapClickedHandler(new ErisImageMap.OnImageMapClickedHandler() 
        {
             public void onImageMapClicked(int id) 
             {
                try
                {
                    if(id==R.id.erispage2next)
                     {  

                        Intent i=new Intent(Erispage2Activity.this,Erispage3Activity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        ErisImageMap.bit.recycle();
                        System.gc();
                        finish();
                        audioStory.stop();
                    }
                    if(id==R.id.erispage2play)
                    {
                        startAnimationPopOut();
                        audioStory.start();
//                      play.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        play.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
//                      play.c
                    }
                    if(id==R.id.erispage2stop)
                    {
                        audioStory.pause();
                        play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        stop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
//                  ErisImageMap.bit.recycle();
                }
             }
             public void onBubbleClicked(int id) 
             {

             }
          });
        }

    private void startAnimationPopOut() 
    {         

        ErisImageMap = (ErisImageMap)findViewById(R.id.map);

        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Erispage2Activity.this,R.anim.fadeout);

         animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() 
         {

            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              overridePendingTransition(R.anim.grid_entry,R.anim.grid_exit);              
            }

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

//              overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein,R.anim.fadeout);
            }

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              overridePendingTransition(R.anim.grid_entry,R.anim.grid_exit);
                overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left );

            }
        });
         ErisImageMap.clearAnimation();
         ErisImageMap.startAnimation(animation);
       }
```

Comment: Which Android version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
android.view.animation.Animation anim = AnimationUtils
                            .loadAnimation(Context, R.anim.slide_up); 
yourLayout.startAnimation(anim);
```

and you have used overridePendingTransition() on animation end... But it will work animation between activities.